# Explanations for cosmic background radiation

Tags: space-expansion, wavelength

I'm wondering if there's a layman's explanation for why the cosmic background radiation is not attributable to the objects in our universe.

For example, is it conceivable in a constantly expanding universe that traditional radiation wavelengths have been widened simply through this expansion?  Or are there calculations of what background radiation we would experience given no CMB observations?

I'm no physicist (forgive my ignorance, I'm a math teacher), but I imagine that visible light on the order of wavelengths of nanometers would be spread out to microwave wavelengths if the universe slowly expanded by 10^6 times.

**Edit:** I'll try to rephrase.  Why is the idea of a huge expansion of an extremely dense and hot universe favored over the idea that there may have been less expansion at a slower rate and that the background is more pedestrian objects with lower wavelengths?

Comment: The CMB *is* attributable to the stuff in our universe albeit from a time when all the stuff was a fairly uniform plasma rather than in the current lumpy and locally inhomogeneous arrangement.

Comment: Maybe I should clarify by saying- how do we know that the background is from the distant past?  My overall questions regards the amount of background radiation that would exist with expansion but not from a singularity

Comment: @dmckee - At the time of recombination, the universe had one temperature with the corresponding black body radiation, so it can probably be assumed that it was in thermodynamic equilibrium. The expansion yields the the present temperature of the blackbody radiation. Doesn't this mean that also now the universe is in thermodynamic equilibrium (also with the CMB) with the same mean temperature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CMB is explained by the occurrences during a time in the very early stages of the universe, called recombination, which is the moment that visible light came into existence. Before recombination, photons were coupled to matter in a hot dense plasma containing photons, electrons and protons. After photons decoupled from matter due to expansion and cooling in the universe, these photons could travel freely through space, and interact with matter.

So the moment that this occurred is what we observe as the cosmic microwave background. The CMB is actually infrared blackbody radiation emitted when the universe was a temperature of ~3000-4000K, which has been redshifted (z = 1100) from the visible to microwave spectrum as you hypothesized.

The CMB is special in the sense that it covers the entire universe (background radiation constant everywhere). This is a result of the fact that the big bang is thought to have happened 'everywhere at once', and thus the CMB is uniform in all directions from any point in space.

Due to localized gravitational forces in a system like our solar system, I don't believe the expansion of the universe could be determined simply from measuring wavelengths on a local scale (one within our solar system). We rely more on measuring redshift of distant objects.

Comment: Very helpful.  So a follow up question- if we noticed the background radiation was not so uniform would we have reason to suspect that the radiation occurred with the universe already spread out?  I'm having trouble still understanding why uniform radiation necessitates close distances.  I imagine, much like heat in a room, that the heat dissipates and is pretty much consistent everywhere.  (At least it would be with sources spread out somewhat homogenously like in our universe)

Comment: Yeah you have the right idea. The CMB was discovered somewhat accidentally by measuring background noise within a radio telescope. At the time, it was thought to be a problem with the telescope as the background noise was constant no matter where the telescope was aimed. There are no other radiation sources that cover the entire universe the way the CMB does.

Comment: So noticing background radiation that is in a localized area, we can assume that it happened in a specific spot (and not everywhere at once like the CMB). The fact that CMB radiation is everywhere is a key indicator that it existed from the early universe.

Comment: Are you at all aware of people calculating the amount of regular background radiation that would be  here if the CMB were not there?  Is there a back of the envelope calculation that could be done to compare to CMB we observe today?

Comment: There isn't really an amount of background radiation that is not CMB radiation. If the CMB were to not exist, the radio antenna that discovered them would have worked as intended - finding more localized radio sources. I don't quite follow what you mean by comparing the CMB to what we observe today. We do observe the CMB today as microwave radiation. We can even discern our direction of motion in the universe by analyzing the dipole moment of our CMB observation. 

Basically, without CMB, we wouldn't see any significant background radiation aside from localized sources.

Comment: This makes sense.  I understand now, I think, that our expected observation is little to no background radiation if CMB from a hot dense universe were not there.  My main thrust I think was whether we should expect a significant amount of background radiation from more pedestrian sources that we see around us.

Comment: I think it would be useful to consider how we look for EMR sources generally. We typically try to observe and collect photons from a localized region where we know what radiation we are searching for. The antenna that discovered CMB was looking for radio waves in a specific location. Instead, no matter where it looked, it found this strange background noise. If the CMB was a different energy radiation outside of what the antenna could detect, we wouldn't see it. Localized background sources are well known to affect experimental data, which is why experiments are designed to shield it out.

Answer (score 0):

The CMB *is explained* by the effect that the expansion of the universe has had on the "traditional radiation wavelengths". However the latter were the wavelengths (black body distribution) of the universe when it was about 300.000 years old with a very high temperature.